# Calculation in Dataframe and Drop/Create Column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given this sample dataframe

```
           Base         Others     B1        B2      Date
ABC                                                                          
Shop       83.04        82.70     0.000     0.000  01012019
Shop       83.04        82.71     0.000     0.000  01012019
Shop       83.02        82.70     0.000     0.000  02012019
Shop       83.02        82.69     0.167     0.000  02012019
Shop       82.98        82.67     0.227     0.000  03012019
Shop       77.94        77.66     0.640     0.054  03012019
Shop       77.45        77.16     0.354     0.020  04012019
Shop       72.81        72.58     0.125     0.076  04012019
Shop       72.81        72.57     0.012     0.003  05012019
Shop       72.81        72.57     0.000     0.000  05012019
```

I will like to do the following calculation:

(B1-B2)*1000

And place the result in a new column called 'Cal'. At the same time, I will like to drop B1 and B2 out of the dataframe after the calculation.

Calculation wise, I have attempted this line:

```
cal_df = df.loc[((pd.to_numeric(df['B1']))-(pd.to_numeric(df['B2'])))*1000]
```

But received a KeyError that shows the dataframe values (no real error sentence actually came out).

Can someone advise on this? Perhaps I need to use numpy or groupby functions? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract columns - after subtract are removed from original DataFrame:

```
df['new'] = (df.pop('B1') - df.pop('B2'))*1000
```

If need convert to numeric and possible some non numeric values:

```
df['new'] = (pd.to_numeric(df.pop('B1'), errors='coerce') - 
             pd.to_numeric(df.pop('B2'), errors='coerce'))*1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
df['CAL'] = (df['B1']- df['B2']) * 1000
```